# HPLC Columns For Compounds Not Soluble In Non- Or Low Polar Solvents

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, separation-techniques

Can someone recommend HPLC columns for compounds which are not soluble in no- or low polar solvents (hexane, isopropanol, toluene, and dichloromethane)?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is reverse phase hplc which employs a polar mobile phase.

Answer (score 4):

Try searching Google Scholar and write HPLC separation and the names of your compounds. You will find plenty of publications and of course column names. If your compounds are new, you should test the solubility in MeOH, ACN, and 50:50 MeOH/H2O and 50:50 ACN/H2O. Do they dissolve in such solvents systems? If they do, you would use C-18 RPLC columns. There are literally hundreds of columns with similar C-18 chemistry.

If your compound is highly polar (carboxylates, amines, phosphates etc.), even bare silica column can do the separation. This technique is called HILIC. I have written several articles on HILIC. Try Google Scholar for reviews on HILIC.

Comment: Very detailed articles. I just found what I need there. Many thanks! Great forum, Love~